# Get the Instagram image page link using PHP API

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm trying to fetch images by using hashtags, and want to get the direct link of the actuall Instagram image page not the image link.
like this link : http://instagram.com/p/oRANLioVee/
But i wasn't able to do that, here is my code:

```
function callInstagram($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }
    // Set number of photos to show

    // Set height and width for photos
    $count = '9999';
    $tag = 'mytag';
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id=765390678573452431546477809798&count='.$count;

    $inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
    $results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);

    foreach($results['data'] as $item){
    $image_link = $item['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
    $fullsize = $item['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$fullsize.'"><img src="'.$image_link.'" /></a>';
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
And although, i set the count to 9999 but i just got 33 images.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`count` doesn't seem to be a valid parameter for the `/tags` endpoint. The documentation is here:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

The data is paginated when it is returned so you need to use `MIN_ID` and `MAX_ID` to page through results.

Comment: `max_id` and `min_id` is little confusing for me, how can i use them?